# why can't I import my models in Python shell?

Tags: django, django-models, django-settings

I don't even know what this is. Works fine when I `runserver`. But I get an Error when trying to import in the Python Shell.

My app is called `auctions` and my `models.py` (using `AbstractUser`) file is:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="portraits", blank=True, default="default.jpg")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.username}"


class Category(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}"


class Item(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="inventory")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, default="Megamind.jpg")
    starting_bid = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="1", related_name="stuff")
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    favorited = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name="favorites")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} of {self.owner}"
```

[image: Python Shell]

Comment: Try using the django shell - `python manage.py shell`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `python manage.py shell`. In this way it automatically imports settings that are important for django related modules import.